# Date manipulation in C++

Tags: c++, date

I am sure that this kind of questions must have been asked before, but failed to find anything by searching this site. My apologies in advance if I missed any similar questions.

1. Is there anything in C++ that just does date manipulation at all?
   I am aware of SYSTEMTIME structure (it is the structure returned when you do GetSystemTime I think) but it does not seem to contain any manipulation functions. For example, I am looking at something which can do "give me the day of the second Tuesday in July 2010". Also, fitting a time not sourced from the system clock into a SYSTEMTIME structure just seems, well, wrong.
2. Is there any library routine to validate a date at all? I am not thinking about the basic "check day is between 1 and 28". The routine must be able to say that 29-02-2009 does not exist, for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should check out  [Boost::DateTime](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/date_time.html).

But to answer your question there is no date time 'handling' as such in C++

Comment: Another option is [chrono::date](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/bloomington/date.html).

Answer (score 2):

The SYSTEMTIME structure and GetSystemTime() function are Windows API functions and aren't really part of the core language or standard library. I know this is a little picky but this might save some embarrassment later on if someone who isn't on Windows reads this.

I'd certainly second the recommendation for the Boost::DateTime library that Chris made. That aside if you want to write standard C++ you've really only got the old C date and time functions that are also in [ctime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/). But unless you're really stuck in a shop where you can't use boost for whatever reason, I'd go with Boost::DateTime.

Comment: There are a million and five (well almost) bolt on libraries which handle time, The Boost::DateTime is the one I would recommend. ctime, is strictly speaking a UNIX thing, and of course it's C not C++!

Comment: I agree regarding the number of libraries and I've amended my answer to make it a bit clearer. Just to make things even clearer, yes, ctime is based on the Unix time functions but it is part of the C++ standard as well.